# NextJS client-side data is there but not rendering

Tags: reactjs, typescript, next.js

I am trying to render data on a blog page. The data is fetched client side and is returning accurately as I can see it when I `console.log()`. However, it doesn't render the data on the page, it's just empty elements. Im absolutely stumped.

```
interface Post {
  content?: string;
  title?: string;
  date?: string;
}

export default async function Page({ params }: { params: Params }) {
  const [post, setPost] = useState<Post>();

  const fetchData = async () => {
    try {
      const data = await getPost(params.slug);
      setPost(data.post);
    } catch (error) {
      console.error('Error fetching data:', error);
    }
  };

 useEffect(() => {
    fetchData();
  }, []);

 return (
      <>
        <h1>{post?.title}</h1>
        <p>{post?.date}</p>
        <p>{post?.content}</p>
      </>
    );
};
```

and this is the layout

```
import { Inter } from 'next/font/google'

const inter = Inter({ subsets: ['latin'] })

export default function RootLayout({
  children,
}: {
  children: React.ReactNode
}) {
  return (
    <>
      {children}
    </>
    )
}
```

data is returning an object in this format

```
{content: "Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet", date: "11/29/23", title: "hello-world"
```

any advice or help would be greatly appreciated. thanks!

Comment: You have a typo in the post. could it be the issue? 

        <h1>{post?.title}<h1>
You need to close the h1 tag.

Comment: @am0m0rajab no that's not it

Comment: what is your `getPost` function returning. Can you log that and let us know?

Comment: @skellertor my bad, i just edited the original post and added the returned object

Comment: I can't answer because my account is limited for some reason but I fixed it by converting to a functional component
```const Page = ({ params }: { params: Params }) => {
```

Answer (score 0):

If the data object that is returned looks like

```
{ content: "lorem impsum", date: "11/29/23:, title: "hello world" }
```

Then you are probably setting state incorrectly. Instead of

```
setPost(data.post);
```

Try

```
setPost(data);
```